# Modified PHP form not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have downloaded this "subscribe to our newsletter" script from [here](http://www.phpjabbers.com/).

The script contains a form and a mySQL database with 6 fields: `id`, `email`, `name`, `date_subscribe`, `date_unsubscribe` and `status`.

The form is very simple: type your email, type your name and subscribe.

I need to do a modification to this form/database to add an extra field I call `promotion`. I have edited the mySQL database and added `promotion` as varchar(250) after `status`.

I have modified the PHP script to include this new field but when I submit the form, the content on the new `promotion` field is not added to the database.

I have checked the code and form several times and I don't see the problem.

This is the form HTML after the modification (my modifications are marked):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Subscription form</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
        <form id="subscribe-form" class="subscribe-form hide">
            <div class="form-title">Subscribe to our newsletter</div>
            <hr>
            <div class="form-loading hide"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i></div>
            <div class="form-message hide">
                Thank you for subscribing!</div>
            <div class="form-content">
                <div class="group">
                    <label for="email">Your email</label>
                    <div class="input-prefix">
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        <input id="email" name="email" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Your email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="group">
                    <label for="name">Your name</label>
                    <div class="input-prefix">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                        <input id="name" name="name" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Your name">
                    </div>
                </div>

I HAVE ADDED THIS SECTION
===========================

                <div class="group">
                    <label for="promotion">PROMOTION NAME (Fill this with the promotion name)</label>
                    <div class="input-prefix">
                        <input id="promotion" name="promotion" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Promotion Name">
                    </div>
                </div>

============================

                <div class="group group-submit">
                    <label class="empty"></label>
                    <div align="right"><button class="btn-submit" type="submit">Subscribe</button></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--<div class="form-footer">
                <a class="btn" data-toggle="unsubscribe" href="#">Unsubscribe</a>
            </div>-->
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="subscribe">
        </form>

        <form id="unsubscribe-form" class="subscribe-form hide">
            <div class="form-title unsubscribe">Unsubscribe from our newsletter</div>
            <hr>
            <div class="form-loading hide"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i></div>
            <div class="form-message hide">
                You've been unsubscribed.</div>
            <div class="form-content">
                <div class="group">
                    <label for="unsubscribe_email">Your email</label>
                    <div class="input-prefix">
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        <input id="unsubscribe_email" name="unsubscribe_email" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Your email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="group">
                    <label class="empty"></label>
                    <div>
                        <input id="confirm" type="checkbox" name="confirm" value="T">
                        <label for="confirm">Click to confirm you want to unsubscribe</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="group group-submit">
                    <label class="empty"></label>
                    <div align="right"><button class="btn-submit" type="submit">Unsubscribe</button></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-footer">
                <a class="btn" data-toggle="subscribe" href="#">Subscribe</a>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="unsubscribe">
        </form>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>     
        <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the PHP that populates the database and my modifications:

```
<?php
###########################################################
/*
Subscription Form
Copyright (C) StivaSoft ltd. All rights Reserved.

This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program.  If not, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html.

For further information visit:
http://www.phpjabbers.com/
info@phpjabbers.com

*/
###########################################################

# CONFIG
define('_DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('_DB_NAME', 'news');
define('_DB_USER', 'admin_xxxx');
define('_DB_PASS', 'xxx');


$subscribe = (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'unsubscribe')?false:true;

if ($subscribe){
    $fields = array(
        array('name' => 'email', 'valid' => array('require', 'email')),
        array('name' => 'name', 'valid' => array('require')),
    );
}else{
    $fields = array(
        array('name' => 'unsubscribe_email', 'valid' => array('require', 'email')),
        array('name' => 'confirm', 'valid' => array('require'), 'err_message' => 'Please confirm'),
    );
}

// Connect to database
$connection = mysql_connect(_DB_HOST, _DB_USER, _DB_PASS) or die ('Unable to connect to MySQL server.<br ><br >Please make sure your MySQL login details are correct.');
$db = mysql_select_db(_DB_NAME, $connection) or die ('request "Unable to select database."');

$error_fields = array();
$get = array();
foreach ($fields AS $field){
    $value = isset($_POST[$field['name']])?$_POST[$field['name']]:'';
    if (is_array($value)){
        $value = implode('/ ', $value);
    }
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }
    $get[$field['name']] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    $is_valid = true;
    $err_message = '';
    if (!empty($field['valid'])){
        foreach ($field['valid'] AS $valid) {
            switch ($valid) {
                case 'require':
                    $is_valid = $is_valid && strlen($value) > 0;
                    $err_message = 'Field required';
                    break;
                case 'email':
                    $is_valid = $is_valid && preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", $value);
                    $err_message = 'Email required';
                    break;
                default:                
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!$is_valid){
        if (!empty($field['err_message'])){
            $err_message = $field['err_message'];
        }
        $error_fields[] = array('name' => $field['name'], 'message' => $err_message);
    }
}

if (empty($error_fields)){
    if ($subscribe){
        $data = array(
            'email' => "'".$get['email']."'",
            'name' => "'".$get['name']."'",
            'date_subscribe' => 'NOW()',
            'status' => "'T'",


 I HAVE ADDED THIS
============================================

            'promotion' => "'".$get['promotion']."'"

============================================

        );
        $sql = "REPLACE INTO subscription_form (`".implode("`, `", array_keys($data))."`) VALUES(".implode(", ", array_values($data)).")";
    }else{
        $sql = "UPDATE subscription_form SET date_unsubscribe = NOW(), status = 'F' WHERE email = '".$get['unsubscribe_email']."'";
    }
    if (!empty($sql)){
        $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
    }
    echo (json_encode(array('code' => 'success')));
}else{
    echo json_encode(array('code' => 'failed', 'fields' => $error_fields));
}
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Are you alright with that password being public?

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Have you done a `print_r($_POST)` to make sure the value is getting posted properly?

Comment: @JayBlanchard, he escapes every argument with `mysql_real_escape_string`, and then puts it into quotes -- how is it at risk of injection?

Comment: Escaping isn't enough. There are known holes with the `mysql_*` API and it has been proven time and again that injection can occur.

Comment: Did you get this script to work eventually? it seems to not support PHP 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this in your php?

```
if ($subscribe){
$fields = array(
    array('name' => 'email', 'valid' => array('require', 'email')),
    array('name' => 'name', 'valid' => array('require')),
    array('name' => 'promotion', 'valid' => array()),
);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the issue as the actual query is only using the $data array for both keys and values.

Comment: foreach ($fields AS $field){ is saying here are the valid vields we will accept lets process them. ($get) The new field wasn't in the list.

Comment: ok but you are marking promotion as require and it is not required. User can leave it empty.

Comment: the db insert is populated by $get which gets assigned by looping through the $fields array.

Comment: I got it. THANKS again.

Answer (score 0):

In your php try to change this

```
'promocao' => "'".$get['promocao']."'"
```

to this

```
'promocao' => "'".$get['promotion']."'"
```

Since your input field is `name="promotion"` 
And also be aware that in DB field name is `promocao` If not and if in your DB your field name is promotion then change it like this

```
'promotion' => "'".$get['promotion']."'"
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was just a typo when I copied it here. Fixed. The problem persists.

Comment: like I said, this was just a typo when I copied the code to here. The db field is called promotion and the form field too.

Comment: o and tell me other fields are inserted into db just this one not?

Comment: and can your `print_r($get);` and see if var $get contain at all this promotion value

Answer (score 0):

Also add the `promotion` field here:

```php
if ($subscribe){
    $fields = array(
        array('name' => 'email', 'valid' => array('require', 'email')),
        array('name' => 'name', 'valid' => array('require')),
    );
```